# ruby on rails 4 foreign key and association to access another table's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, foreign-key-relationship, model-associations

The question is how can I list all the assets associated to each Project?

Here is what I have so far:
I have a project model and asset model. a project can have many assets (uploaded by Carrier wave)

here is the project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, length: { maximum: 150 } ,uniqueness: true, presence: true
    has_many :assets
end
```

and here is the asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader 
    belongs_to:project
end
```

In my index method in project_controller.rb ,I have the following instance variables:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @assets = Asset.all
     end

  def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title,assets_attributes: [:id,:project_id,:attachment])
  end
end
```

and this is the view, index.html.erb which lists all the assets not the one associated with the project

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <td><%= project.title %></td>
        <% @assets.each do |asset| %>
            <td><%= asset.attachment.size %></td> 
         <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: in my index file I want the assets associated to each project, with this code I have all the assets for each project. I do not know how to add a where clause or condition to fix it.

Comment: You just have to do `project.assets` to get the assets of the current project.

Comment: Well I tried that, thats why I am writing here, it raises this error ` undefined method `attachment' for #<Asset::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fed63e97e08> `

Comment: Giving the error is a good idea then. Help us help you ;)

Comment: Your error means that your asset instance doesn't have an `attachment` method for some reason. Check in the rails console, load an asset, and try to get its attachment.

Comment: It does have attachment,I see it in the related tables and by the code that I demonstrated in my question I have no error

Comment: In the console, do this: `asset = Asset.last; project = asset.project; assets = project.assets`. No errors? Also, can you add the exact code of your view when you tried `project.assets.each do |asset|... end` to your question?

Comment: OMG, I made a terrible mistake. Yes `project.assets.each do |asset|` works

Comment: CAn you add it as an answer so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should look like this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <td><%= project.title %></td>
    <% project.assets.each do |asset| %>
        <td><%= asset.attachment.size %></td> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to remove `@assets = Asset.all` from your controller, and think about adding pagination.

Also, to avoid N+1 queries in your view, you can do

```
@projects = Project.includes(:assets) # you dont need .all, I think it's deprecated in rails 4 when you use it this way
```

in your controller. That will load all the needed projects in 1 query.

And if you only need the size attribute from assets, you can do this to make it more efficient:

```
@projects = Project.includes(:assets).select('projects.*, assets.size').references(:assets)
```